# Using pexpect and winpexpect

Tags: python, pexpect

I have a program that uses pexpect that needs to run on both windows and linux. pexpect and winpexpect have the same API, with the exception of the spawn method. What's the best way to support both in my code?

I was thinking something along these lines:

```
import pexpect

use_winpexpect = True

try:
    import winpexpect
except ImportError:
    use_winpexpect = False

# Much later

if use_winpexpect:
    winpexpect.winspawn()
else:
    pexpect.spawn()
```

But I'm not sure if this would work or is a good idea.

Comment: It doesn't help you much at the moment, but in the next version of pexpect, we'll be folding back in one of the versions with Windows support, so there will be one API for both.

Answer (score 0):

It may be easier to check the OS type (info that may be useful downstream as well as for how you create an expect session object) and make your import decision based upon that. A practical example that spawns the shell appropriate to the OS, and based upon OS sets the prompt we will be looking for later in the script to identify when a command is complete:

```
# what platform is this script on?
import sys
if 'darwin' in sys.platform:
    my_os = 'osx'
    import pexpect
elif 'linux' in sys.platform:
    my_os = 'linux'
    import pexpect
elif 'win32' in sys.platform:
    my_os = 'windows'
    import winpexpect
else:
    my_os = 'unknown:' + sys.platform
    import pexpect

# now spawn the shell and set the prompt
prompt = 'MYSCRIPTPROMPT' # something we would never see in this session
if my_os == 'windows':
    command = 'cmd.exe'
    session = winpexpect.winspawn(command)
    session.sendline('prompt ' + prompt)
    session.expect(prompt) # this catches the setting of the prompt
    session.expect(prompt) # this catches the prompt itself.
else:
    command = '/bin/sh'
    session = pexpect.spawn(command)
    session.sendline('export PS1=' + prompt)
    session.expect(prompt) # this catches the setting of the prompt
    session.expect(prompt) # this catches the prompt itself.
```

Comment: Yes, this is pretty much what I ended up doing.